# $ \triangle ABC$ is a right triangle, $AX$ bisects $\angle A$ and ...

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Assume $ \triangle ABC$ is a right triangle where $\angle C= 90°$. Suppose that
$ \overline {AX} $ bisects $\angle A$ and point $X$ lies on $BC$. Assume that the circumcircle of triangle $AXB$ intersects $AC$ on $Y$.

a) Show that if lengths $BC$ and $CY$ are intergers divisible by a prime $p$, then $AY$ is also an intenger divisible by $p$.

b) Show that if $CY= k$ and $BC= 3k$ ($k$ is an interger), then the lengths of sides of the triangle $ABC$ must be intergers.

This is what I have done:

Aplying power of point of $C$, we get:

$$CY (CA) = (CX)(CB)$$

$$CY(CY+AY)= CB(CB -XB)$$

$$ (CY)^2+ CY(AY) = (CB)^2 - CB(XB)$$

$$CY(AY) = (CB)^2 - (CY)^2 - CB(XB)$$

$$ AY = \frac{(CB)^2 - (CY)^2 - CB(XB)}{CY}$$

But this doesn't prove that $AY$ is divisible by $p$ or that it is an interger.

[image]

I did that considering this figure. I think I may be wrong because that might not be what a circumcircle is.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\angle BAX = \angle XAY$ and $BXYA$ are concyclic, it means that $BX=XY$. Thus

$$
CX = BC - BX \land CX^2 = BX^2 - CY^2
$$
$$
(BC - BX)^2 = BX^2 - CY^2
$$
$$
BC^2 + BX^2 - 2BC\cdot BX = BX^2 - CY^2
$$
$$
BX = \frac{BC^2+CY^2}{2BC}
$$
From the power of the point:
$$
AC = \frac{BC\cdot BX}{CY} = \frac{BC^2 +CY^2}{2CY}
$$
Why is it divisible by $p$?

Comment: I think that from what you did it´s possible to show that $AY$ is divisible by $p$. Note that I had found that $ CY(AY) = (CB)^2 - (CY)^2 - CB(XB) $, changing $XB$ (what you found), we´d have: $ CY(AY) = (CB)^2 - (CY)^2 - CB( \frac{BC^2+CY^2}{2BC})$, solving the equations we would have: $AY= \frac {BC^2 - 3(CY)^2}{2CY}$, now let $BC$ equal $ap$ and $CY$, $bp$, we would have: $AY= \frac {a^2(p^2)}{2bp} - \frac{3bp}{2}$, and then factoring $p$, we´d have: $AY = p( \frac {a^2}{2b} - {3b}{2})$ . If this $ \frac {a^2}{2b} -  \frac {3b}{2} $ were an interger, then $AY$ would be divisible by $p$.

Comment: @Vmimi if $p|CY$ and $p|AC$ then $p|AC-CY = AY$.

Comment: But I think that your power point would be incorrect, it would be: $$CA = \frac {CX \cdot CB}{CY}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Join the points $B$ and $Y$. Then study the triangles $BCY$ and $ACX$, which are similar. If we let $CB=m=pa, CY=n=pb, AY=M, CX=N$, then by we have that $$\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{CY}{CX}=\frac{BY}{AX}.$$ From there you get two equations in the unknowns $M$ and $N$, which we can solve for $M$, which should tell us what we seek.

For the second part, we now know the sides of $\triangle ABC$, we can study them (after making appropriate substitutions) to see how they are integers given the constraints.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that but I think that doesn't give me any information to solve the problem.

Comment: @Vmimi I have included a little more detail. See if that helps.

Comment: It´s true what you say but would $AY$ always be an interger in the first point?

Comment: @Vmimi If you got this problem from a standard source then we know that it must be, if all our steps are correct. But we cannot find out until we solve the system for $M$. It would be tedious, but a computer algebra package may help.

Answer (score -1):

You might find it useful:
The power of point equation you wrote is correct.
$CY⋅CA=CX⋅CB$
Also, according to the internal bisector theorem:
$\frac{CX}{CA}=\frac{BX}{AB}$